# Rails omniauth devise mongodb in docker

Tags: ruby-on-rails, mongodb, devise, omniauth, doorkeeper

Any answer would be very much appreciated, as we have been struggling with this issue for the past 1 - 1.5 months.

The error we are receiving is as follows:

Error: Completed 302 Found on the oauth provider
       oauth client does go in OmniauthCallbacksController but does not get in action doorkeeper

This time we are using:

```
Docker version 1.9.1
two microservices:
  mainview_m (oauth_client)
     mongo (2.2.2)
     mongoid (5.0.2)
     devise (3.5.6)
     omniauth (1.3.1)
     omniauth-oauth2 (1.3.1)
  authentication_m (oauth_provider)
     pg (0.18.4)
     devise (3.5.6)
     doorkeeper (3.1.0)
```

---

**The different classes within the oauth_client:**

---

```
 class Users::OmniauthCallbacksController < Devise::OmniauthCallbacksController
      raise "here after trying to authenticate, the app goes and has the following 

    _________________________________________________________
    rack session:
     #<ActionDispatch::Request::Session:0x007fe885b48b68 @by=#<ActionDispatch::Session::CookieStore:0x007fe8abb56d78 @app=#<ActionDispatch::Flash:0x007fe8abb56da0 @app=#<ActionDispatch::ParamsParser:0x007fe8abb56e68 @app=#<Rack::Head:0x007fe8abb56e90 @app=#<Rack::ConditionalGet:0x007fe8abb56eb8 @app=#<Rack::ETag:0x007fe8abb56ee0 @app=#<Warden::Manager:0x007fe8abb56fd0 @config={:default_scope=>:user, :scope_defaults=>{}, :default_strategies=>{:user=>[:rememberable, :database_authenticatable]}, :intercept_401=>false, :failure_app=>#<Devise::Delegator:0x007fe8ad0bac50>}, @app=#<OmniAuth::Strategies::Doorkeeper>>, @cache_control="max-age=0, private, must-revalidate", @no_cache_control="no-cache">>>, @parsers={#<Mime::Type:0x007fe8ab600090 @synonyms=["text/x-json", "application/jsonrequest"], @symbol=:json, @string="application/json", @hash=1122954549396747880>=>:json}>>, @default_options={:path=>"/", :domain=>nil, :expire_after=>nil, :secure=>false, :httponly=>true, :defer=>false, :renew=>false}, @key="_mainview_m_session", @cookie_only=true>, @env={"GATEWAY_INTERFACE"=>"CGI/1.1", "PATH_INFO"=>"/users/auth/doorkeeper/callback", "QUERY_STRING"=>"", "REMOTE_ADDR"=>"172.16.90.1", "REMOTE_HOST"=>"172.16.90.1", "REQUEST_METHOD"=>"GET", "REQUEST_URI"=>"http:/users/auth/doorkeeper/callback", "SCRIPT_NAME"=>"", "SERVER_PORT"=>"80", "SERVER_PROTOCOL"=>"HTTP/1.1", "SERVER_SOFTWARE"=>"WEBrick/1.3.1 (Ruby/2.3.0/2015-12-25)", "HTTP_HOST"=>"mainview_m.awe.docker:3030", "HTTP_CONNECTION"=>"keep-alive", "HTTP_ACCEPT"=>"text/html,application/xhtml+xml,application/xml;q=0.9,image/webp,*/*;q=0.8", "HTTP_UPGRADE_INSECURE_REQUESTS"=>"1", "HTTP_USER_AGENT"=>"Mozilla/5.0 (Macintosh; Intel Mac OS X 10_11_3) AppleWebKit/537.36 (KHTML, like Gecko) Chrome/48.0.2564.109 Safari/537.36", "HTTP_REFERER"=>"http://mainview_m.awe.docker:3030/", "HTTP_ACCEPT_ENCODING"=>"gzip, deflate, sdch", "HTTP_ACCEPT_LANGUAGE"=>"de-DE,de;q=0.8,en-US;q=0.6,en;q=0.4", "HTTP_COOKIE"=>"_mainview_m_session=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%3D%3D--ebafe0fc589fd91cf221390a44fd33a568c512d3", "rack.version"=>[1, 3], "rack.input"=>#<StringIO:0x007fe885aed9c0>, "rack.errors"=>#<IO:<STDERR>>, "rack.multithread"=>true, "rack.multiprocess"=>false, "rack.run_once"=>false, "rack.url_scheme"=>"http", "rack.hijack?"=>true, "rack.hijack"=>#<Proc:0x007fe885aed6c8@/usr/local/bundle/gems/rack-1.6.4/lib/rack/handler/webrick.rb:76 (lambda)>, "rack.hijack_io"=>nil, "HTTP_VERSION"=>"HTTP/1.1", "REQUEST_PATH"=>"/users/auth/doorkeeper/callback", "ORIGINAL_FULLPATH"=>"/users/auth/doorkeeper/callback", "ORIGINAL_SCRIPT_NAME"=>"", "action_dispatch.routes"=>#<ActionDispatch::Routing::RouteSet:0x007fe8ab03c3c0>, "action_dispatch.parameter_filter"=>[:password], "action_dispatch.redirect_filter"=>[], "action_dispatch.secret_token"=>nil, "action_dispatch.secret_key_base"=>"7b424e3f13cf9f72df32681aa77fac6cfbc534bda80362220e5d63e0b8ca21394ad64e47ec7eacc4a7e7bbefc74bfa707627275ec68560de0f89c7e09ef31dfb", "action_dispatch.show_exceptions"=>true, "action_dispatch.show_detailed_exceptions"=>true, "action_dispatch.logger"=>#<ActiveSupport::Logger:0x007fe8ab01f590 @progname=nil, @level=0, @default_formatter=#<Logger::Formatter:0x007fe8ab01f518 @datetime_format=nil>, @formatter=#<ActiveSupport::Logger::SimpleFormatter:0x007fe8ab54ccc0 @datetime_format=nil>, @logdev=#<Logger::LogDevice:0x007fe8ab01f4c8 @shift_size=nil, @shift_age=nil, @filename=nil, @dev=#<File:/app/log/development.log>, @mon_owner=nil, @mon_count=0, @mon_mutex=#<Thread::Mutex:0x007fe8ab01f4a0>>>, "action_dispatch.backtrace_cleaner"=>#<Rails::BacktraceCleaner:0x007fe8840287e8 @filters=[#<Proc:0x007fe8840286d0@/usr/local/bundle/gems/railties-4.2.5.1/lib/rails/backtrace_cleaner.rb:14>, #<Proc:0x007fe8840286a8@/usr/local/bundle/gems/railties-4.2.5.1/lib/rails/backtrace_cleaner.rb:15>, #<Proc:0x007fe884028680@/usr/local/bundle/gems/railties-4.2.5.1/lib/rails/backtrace_cleaner.rb:16>, #<Proc:0x007fe884028310@/usr/local/bundle/gems/railties-4.2.5.1/lib/rails/backtrace_cleaner.rb:29>], @silencers=[#<Proc:0x007fe8840282e8@/usr/local/bundle/gems/railties-4.2.5.1/lib/rails/backtrace_cleaner.rb:19>], @root="/app/">, "action_dispatch.key_generator"=>#<ActiveSupport::CachingKeyGenerator:0x007fe8acdd2b00 @key_generator=#<ActiveSupport::KeyGenerator:0x007fe8acdd2b28 @secret="7b424e3f13cf9f72df32681aa77fac6cfbc534bda80362220e5d63e0b8ca21394ad64e47ec7eacc4a7e7bbefc74bfa707627275ec68560de0f89c7e09ef31dfb", @iterations=1000>, @cache_keys=#<ThreadSafe::Cache:0x007fe8acdd2ad8 @backend={"signed_global_ids64"=>"\xCBF\x8A\xB8@S\xEA\xC6\xB6Y\xE4p\x87\x8BQ\x98\xA5F\xD3\x83\x83\x95[\x06Y\xA0\xF8\xAE\xA5\x99\x883\xE9\xA0\xFFH,\x91\xEC\x91)t\xCB!\x81\\\x06\xB8\xFB\x19\xD0\x92\xC5\x8D|\xF5\xB8 $\xB9\xC4->J", "encrypted cookie64"=>"OUg\xD7=\xBCI5\eY4\x17'h\x94\x81\xCE\x80\xD0\x1A\x97P\xB2\xBB%\xA8\xB6bml6\x99\xFD\x19^vU\xC9i\x9D\xBE\x9E\x95:@\xA3M\x8F\xF0\x1D\x91_\x9EV8\xB3\x85\xE8m\x1E \xBB\xE3*", "signed encrypted cookie64"=>"\x94=\xCE\xB6p\xD6\xE5eh\xF468\x19\x87\xB3\xD1\v\x91[\x1D\xC4\xB9\xAA\xC9\x81\xEE\xDAoRv\x89yB\x9F\xAA\xB2\xFD\xA4=;5\r\xC0X\xFE-`\x88G\xD9u\xFES\x8F\xDB\x9C\xEE\xE2\xBCv|\xDD\n\x0F", "signed cookie64"=>"\x9D\xE3\xFA\x0E\xB0\xE0\xF6j\xE85Z\x8C\xB8Qa\n\xB7\xA0\xF2\xC3\xC6MN\xAF\xC0\x01p\xE0\xEE~\xBA\v'\xB4qO\\4\x8A\x00\x03\x8B\xEA\xAE\x91\xC2\xAD\xE3\xEE~f\x15t\x80\x84q\xE5>;Sx\x89\xE7\xEE"}, @default_proc=nil>>, "action_dispatch.http_auth_salt"=>"http authentication", "action_dispatch.signed_cookie_salt"=>"signed cookie", "action_dispatch.encrypted_cookie_salt"=>"encrypted cookie", "action_dispatch.encrypted_signed_cookie_salt"=>"signed encrypted cookie", "action_dispatch.cookies_serializer"=>:json, "action_dispatch.cookies_digest"=>nil, "ROUTES_70318639145440_SCRIPT_NAME"=>"", "action_dispatch.request_id"=>"62058d9c-ff36-45d9-8621-96a36d4a3d84", "action_dispatch.remote_ip"=>#<ActionDispatch::RemoteIp::GetIp:0x007fe885b4ad50 @env={...}, @check_ip=true, @proxies=[#<IPAddr: IPv4:127.0.0.1/255.255.255.255>, #<IPAddr: IPv6:0000:0000:0000:0000:0000:0000:0000:0001/ffff:ffff:ffff:ffff:ffff:ffff:ffff:ffff>, #<IPAddr: IPv6:fc00:0000:0000:0000:0000:0000:0000:0000/fe00:0000:0000:0000:0000:0000:0000:0000>, #<IPAddr: IPv4:10.0.0.0/255.0.0.0>, #<IPAddr: IPv4:172.16.0.0/255.240.0.0>, #<IPAddr: IPv4:192.168.0.0/255.255.0.0>]>, "rack.session"=>#<ActionDispatch::Request::Session:0x007fe885b48b68 ...>, "rack.session.options"=>#<ActionDispatch::Request::Session::Options:0x007fe885b48af0 @by=#<ActionDispatch::Session::CookieStore:0x007fe8abb56d78 @app=#<ActionDispatch::Flash:0x007fe8abb56da0 @app=#<ActionDispatch::ParamsParser:0x007fe8abb56e68 @app=#<Rack::Head:0x007fe8abb56e90 @app=#<Rack::ConditionalGet:0x007fe8abb56eb8 @app=#<Rack::ETag:0x007fe8abb56ee0 @app=#<Warden::Manager:0x007fe8abb56fd0 @config={:default_scope=>:user, :scope_defaults=>{}, :default_strategies=>{:user=>[:rememberable, :database_authenticatable]}, :intercept_401=>false, :failure_app=>#<Devise::Delegator:0x007fe8ad0bac50>}, @app=#<OmniAuth::Strategies::Doorkeeper>>, @cache_control="max-age=0, private, must-revalidate", @no_cache_control="no-cache">>>, @parsers={#<Mime::Type:0x007fe8ab600090 @synonyms=["text/x-json", "application/jsonrequest"], @symbol=:json, @string="application/json", @hash=1122954549396747880>=>:json}>>, @default_options={:path=>"/", :domain=>nil, :expire_after=>nil, :secure=>false, :httponly=>true, :defer=>false, :renew=>false}, @key="_mainview_m_session", @cookie_only=true>, @env={...}, @delegate={:path=>"/", :domain=>nil, :expire_after=>nil, :secure=>false, :httponly=>true, :defer=>false, :renew=>false, :id=>"571a6fd5c4032241a4f5f08638f33d7b"}>, "warden"=>Warden::Proxy:70318326170920 @config={:default_scope=>:user, :scope_defaults=>{}, :default_strategies=>{:user=>[:rememberable, :database_authenticatable]}, :intercept_401=>false, :failure_app=>#<Devise::Delegator:0x007fe8ad0bac50>}, "omniauth.strategy"=>#<OmniAuth::Strategies::Doorkeeper>, "rack.request.cookie_hash"=>{"_mainview_m_session"=>"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--ebafe0fc589fd91cf221390a44fd33a568c512d3"}, "rack.request.cookie_string"=>"_mainview_m_session=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%3D%3D--ebafe0fc589fd91cf221390a44fd33a568c512d3", "action_dispatch.cookies"=>#<ActionDispatch::Cookies::CookieJar:0x007fe885b27878 @key_generator=#<ActiveSupport::CachingKeyGenerator:0x007fe8acdd2b00 @key_generator=#<ActiveSupport::KeyGenerator:0x007fe8acdd2b28 @secret="7b424e3f13cf9f72df32681aa77fac6cfbc534bda80362220e5d63e0b8ca21394ad64e47ec7eacc4a7e7bbefc74bfa707627275ec68560de0f89c7e09ef31dfb", @iterations=1000>, @cache_keys=#<ThreadSafe::Cache:0x007fe8acdd2ad8 @backend={"signed_global_ids64"=>"\xCBF\x8A\xB8@S\xEA\xC6\xB6Y\xE4p\x87\x8BQ\x98\xA5F\xD3\x83\x83\x95[\x06Y\xA0\xF8\xAE\xA5\x99\x883\xE9\xA0\xFFH,\x91\xEC\x91)t\xCB!\x81\\\x06\xB8\xFB\x19\xD0\x92\xC5\x8D|\xF5\xB8 $\xB9\xC4->J", "encrypted cookie64"=>"OUg\xD7=\xBCI5\eY4\x17'h\x94\x81\xCE\x80\xD0\x1A\x97P\xB2\xBB%\xA8\xB6bml6\x99\xFD\x19^vU\xC9i\x9D\xBE\x9E\x95:@\xA3M\x8F\xF0\x1D\x91_\x9EV8\xB3\x85\xE8m\x1E \xBB\xE3*", "signed encrypted cookie64"=>"\x94=\xCE\xB6p\xD6\xE5eh\xF468\x19\x87\xB3\xD1\v\x91[\x1D\xC4\xB9\xAA\xC9\x81\xEE\xDAoRv\x89yB\x9F\xAA\xB2\xFD\xA4=;5\r\xC0X\xFE-`\x88G\xD9u\xFES\x8F\xDB\x9C\xEE\xE2\xBCv|\xDD\n\x0F", "signed cookie64"=>"\x9D\xE3\xFA\x0E\xB0\xE0\xF6j\xE85Z\x8C\xB8Qa\n\xB7\xA0\xF2\xC3\xC6MN\xAF\xC0\x01p\xE0\xEE~\xBA\v'\xB4qO\\4\x8A\x00\x03\x8B\xEA\xAE\x91\xC2\xAD\xE3\xEE~f\x15t\x80\x84q\xE5>;Sx\x89\xE7\xEE"}, @default_proc=nil>>, @set_cookies={}, @delete_cookies={}, @host="mainview_m.awe.docker", @secure=false, @options={:signed_cookie_salt=>"signed cookie", :encrypted_cookie_salt=>"encrypted cookie", :encrypted_signed_cookie_salt=>"signed encrypted cookie", :secret_token=>nil, :secret_key_base=>"7b424e3f13cf9f72df32681aa77fac6cfbc534bda80362220e5d63e0b8ca21394ad64e47ec7eacc4a7e7bbefc74bfa707627275ec68560de0f89c7e09ef31dfb", :upgrade_legacy_signed_cookies=>false, :serializer=>:json, :digest=>nil}, @cookies={"_mainview_m_session"=>"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--ebafe0fc589fd91cf221390a44fd33a568c512d3"}, @committed=false, @encrypted=#<ActionDispatch::Cookies::EncryptedCookieJar:0x007fe885b270f8 @parent_jar=#<ActionDispatch::Cookies::CookieJar:0x007fe885b27878 ...>, @options={:signed_cookie_salt=>"signed cookie", :encrypted_cookie_salt=>"encrypted cookie", :encrypted_signed_cookie_salt=>"signed encrypted cookie", :secret_token=>nil, :secret_key_base=>"7b424e3f13cf9f72df32681aa77fac6cfbc534bda80362220e5d63e0b8ca21394ad64e47ec7eacc4a7e7bbefc74bfa707627275ec68560de0f89c7e09ef31dfb", :upgrade_legacy_signed_cookies=>false, :serializer=>:json, :digest=>nil}, @encryptor=#<ActiveSupport::MessageEncryptor:0x007fe885b26f68 @secret="OUg\xD7=\xBCI5\eY4\x17'h\x94\x81\xCE\x80\xD0\x1A\x97P\xB2\xBB%\xA8\xB6bml6\x99\xFD\x19^vU\xC9i\x9D\xBE\x9E\x95:@\xA3M\x8F\xF0\x1D\x91_\x9EV8\xB3\x85\xE8m\x1E \xBB\xE3*", @sign_secret="\x94=\xCE\xB6p\xD6\xE5eh\xF468\x19\x87\xB3\xD1\v\x91[\x1D\xC4\xB9\xAA\xC9\x81\xEE\xDAoRv\x89yB\x9F\xAA\xB2\xFD\xA4=;5\r\xC0X\xFE-`\x88G\xD9u\xFES\x8F\xDB\x9C\xEE\xE2\xBCv|\xDD\n\x0F", @cipher="aes-256-cbc", @verifier=#<ActiveSupport::MessageVerifier:0x007fe885b26e78 @secret="\x94=\xCE\xB6p\xD6\xE5eh\xF468\x19\x87\xB3\xD1\v\x91[\x1D\xC4\xB9\xAA\xC9\x81\xEE\xDAoRv\x89yB\x9F\xAA\xB2\xFD\xA4=;5\r\xC0X\xFE-`\x88G\xD9u\xFES\x8F\xDB\x9C\xEE\xE2\xBCv|\xDD\n\x0F", @digest="SHA1", @serializer=ActiveSupport::MessageEncryptor::NullSerializer>, @serializer=ActiveSupport::MessageEncryptor::NullSerializer>>, @signed_or_encrypted=#<ActionDispatch::Cookies::EncryptedCookieJar:0x007fe885b270f8 @parent_jar=#<ActionDispatch::Cookies::CookieJar:0x007fe885b27878 ...>, @options={:signed_cookie_salt=>"signed cookie", :encrypted_cookie_salt=>"encrypted cookie", :encrypted_signed_cookie_salt=>"signed encrypted cookie", :secret_token=>nil, :secret_key_base=>"7b424e3f13cf9f72df32681aa77fac6cfbc534bda80362220e5d63e0b8ca21394ad64e47ec7eacc4a7e7bbefc74bfa707627275ec68560de0f89c7e09ef31dfb", :upgrade_legacy_signed_cookies=>false, :serializer=>:json, :digest=>nil}, @encryptor=#<ActiveSupport::MessageEncryptor:0x007fe885b26f68 @secret="OUg\xD7=\xBCI5\eY4\x17'h\x94\x81\xCE\x80\xD0\x1A\x97P\xB2\xBB%\xA8\xB6bml6\x99\xFD\x19^vU\xC9i\x9D\xBE\x9E\x95:@\xA3M\x8F\xF0\x1D\x91_\x9EV8\xB3\x85\xE8m\x1E \xBB\xE3*", @sign_secret="\x94=\xCE\xB6p\xD6\xE5eh\xF468\x19\x87\xB3\xD1\v\x91[\x1D\xC4\xB9\xAA\xC9\x81\xEE\xDAoRv\x89yB\x9F\xAA\xB2\xFD\xA4=;5\r\xC0X\xFE-`\x88G\xD9u\xFES\x8F\xDB\x9C\xEE\xE2\xBCv|\xDD\n\x0F", @cipher="aes-256-cbc", @verifier=#<ActiveSupport::MessageVerifier:0x007fe885b26e78 @secret="\x94=\xCE\xB6p\xD6\xE5eh\xF468\x19\x87\xB3\xD1\v\x91[\x1D\xC4\xB9\xAA\xC9\x81\xEE\xDAoRv\x89yB\x9F\xAA\xB2\xFD\xA4=;5\r\xC0X\xFE-`\x88G\xD9u\xFES\x8F\xDB\x9C\xEE\xE2\xBCv|\xDD\n\x0F", @digest="SHA1", @serializer=ActiveSupport::MessageEncryptor::NullSerializer>, @serializer=ActiveSupport::MessageEncryptor::NullSerializer>>>, "action_dispatch.request.unsigned_session_cookie"=>{"session_id"=>"571a6fd5c4032241a4f5f08638f33d7b", "_csrf_token"=>"g61BEYcVehgbUUY5EVB4j9Ax9mF4FKvBcL5y/K624Z4=", "flash"=>{"discard"=>[], "flashes"=>{"alert"=>"Could not authenticate you from Doorkeeper because \"Csrf detected\"."}}, "omniauth.state"=>"8f2442d5b7510ed60f89579a4b07f794e5a00d0cd8dd2fb3", "omniauth.params"=>{}, "omniauth.origin"=>"http://mainview_m.awe.docker:3030/"}, "omniauth.origin"=>"http://mainview_m.awe.docker:3030/", "omniauth.params"=>{}, "rack.request.query_string"=>"", "rack.request.query_hash"=>{}, "omniauth.error"=>#<OmniAuth::Strategies::OAuth2::CallbackError: OmniAuth::Strategies::OAuth2::CallbackError>, "omniauth.error.type"=>:csrf_detected, "omniauth.error.strategy"=>#<OmniAuth::Strategies::Doorkeeper>, "devise.mapping"=>#<Devise::Mapping:0x007fe8ab0d2eb0 @scoped_path="users", @singular=:user, @class_name="User", @klass=#<Devise::Getter:0x007fe8ab0be640 @name="User">, @path="users", @path_prefix=nil, @sign_out_via=:delete, @format=nil, @router_name=nil, @failure_app=Devise::FailureApp, @controllers={:omniauth_callbacks=>"users/omniauth_callbacks", :sessions=>"devise/sessions", :passwords=>"devise/passwords", :registrations=>"devise/registrations"}, @path_names={:registration=>"", :new=>"new", :edit=>"edit", :sign_in=>"sign_in", :sign_out=>"sign_out", :password=>"password", :sign_up=>"sign_up", :cancel=>"cancel"}, @modules=[:database_authenticatable, :rememberable, :omniauthable, :recoverable, :registerable, :validatable, :trackable], @routes=[:session, :omniauth_callback, :password, :registration], @used_routes=[:session, :omniauth_callback, :password, :registration], @used_helpers=[:session, :omniauth_callback, :password, :registration]>}, @delegate={"session_id"=>"571a6fd5c4032241a4f5f08638f33d7b", "_csrf_token"=>"g61BEYcVehgbUUY5EVB4j9Ax9mF4FKvBcL5y/K624Z4=", "flash"=>{"discard"=>[], "flashes"=>{"alert"=>"Could not authenticate you from Doorkeeper because \"Csrf detected\"."}}, "omniauth.state"=>"8f2442d5b7510ed60f89579a4b07f794e5a00d0cd8dd2fb3"}, @loaded=true, @exists=nil>

        def doorkeeper
           raise "this is not going to be executed"
        end
    end
```

---

```
call within the .erb
<%= link_to "Sign in via doorkeeper", user_omniauth_authorize_path(provider: :doorkeeper) %>
```

---

devise.rb

config.omniauth :doorkeeper, ENV['DOORKEEPER_APP_ID'], ENV['DOORKEEPER_APP_SECRET']

---

user.rb

```
class User
  include Mongoid::Document
  include Mongoid::Timestamps

  # Include default devise modules. Others available are:
  # :confirmable, :lockable, :timeoutable and :omniauthable
  devise :database_authenticatable, :registerable,
         :recoverable, :rememberable, :trackable, :validatable, :omniauthable, omniauth_providers: [:doorkeeper]

  ## Database authenticatable
  field :email,              type: String, default: ""
  field :encrypted_password, type: String, default: ""

  ## Recoverable
  field :reset_password_token,   type: String
  field :reset_password_sent_at, type: Time

  ## Rememberable
  field :remember_created_at, type: Time

  ## Trackable
  field :sign_in_count,       type: Integer, default: 0
  field :current_sign_in_at,  type: Time
  field :last_sign_in_at,     type: Time
  field :current_sign_in_ip,  type: String
  field :last_sign_in_ip,     type: String
```

---

```
doorkeeper.rb

require 'omniauth-oauth2'

module OmniAuth
  module Strategies
    class Doorkeeper < OmniAuth::Strategies::OAuth2
      option :name, :doorkeeper
      option :client_options, {
        site:          ENV['DOORKEEPER_APP_URL'],
        authorize_url: '/oauth/authorize' #ENV['DOORKEEPER_APP_URL'] + 
      }

      uid {
        raw_info['id']
      }

      info do
        {
          email: raw_info['email'],
        }
      end

      extra do
        { raw_info: raw_info }
      end

      def raw_info
        auth = "Bearer " + access_token.token
        @raw_info = HTTParty.get(ENV['DOORKEEPER_APP_URL'] + "/api/v1/user/current_user", :headers => { "Authorization" => auth})
      end
    end
  end
end
```

---

.ENV
DOORKEEPER_APP_ID=9cc1f0e768459c4d0039a4142d28c82f2d9503ae2c8b0fe6b58cfb0b2be49b6f
DOORKEEPER_APP_SECRET=76219e2bf4500f5c7b8842d951cb0bef1a788ddbca7d84673f5b63288921d02a
DOORKEEPER_APP_URL=http://authentication_m.awe.docker:3000

---

```
session_store.rb
Rails.application.config.session_store :cookie_store, key: '_mainview_m_session'
```

---

**The different classes within the oauth_provider:**

```
doorkeeper.rb

Doorkeeper.configure do
  orm :active_record
  resource_owner_authenticator do
    User.find_by_id(session[:user_id]) || redirect_to(params[:redirect_uri])
  end

  resource_owner_from_credentials do |_routes|
    user = User.find_for_database_authentication(email: params[:username])
    user if user && user.valid_password?(params[:password])
  end
  reuse_access_token
  use_refresh_token
  grant_flows %w[password client_credentials]
end
```

---

oauth/applications

```
Application Id:
   9cc1f0e768459c4d0039a4142d28c82f2d9503ae2c8b0fe6b58cfb0b2be49b6f
Secret:
   76219e2bf4500f5c7b8842d951cb0bef1a788ddbca7d84673f5b63288921d02a
Scopes:
Callback urls:
   http://mainview_m.awe.docker:3030/users/auth/doorkeeper/callback
```

---

```
class User < ActiveRecord::Base
  # Use friendly_id on Users
  extend FriendlyId
  friendly_id :friendify, use: :slugged

  # necessary to override friendly_id reserved words
  def friendify
    if username.downcase == "admin"
      "user-#{username}"
    else
      "#{username}"
    end
  end

  # Include default devise modules. Others available are:
  # :confirmable, :lockable, :timeoutable and :omniauthable
  devise :database_authenticatable, 
  #:recoverable, :rememberable, :trackable, :validatable, :confirmable
  :trackable, :validatable

  # Pagination
  paginates_per 100

  # Validations
  # :username
  validates :username, uniqueness: { case_sensitive: false }
  #validates_format_of :username, with: /\A[a-zA-Z0-9]*\z/, on: :create, message: "can only contain letters and digits"
  validates :username, length: { in: 3..15 }
  # :email
  validates_format_of :email, with: /\A([^@\s]+)@((?:[-a-z0-9]+\.)+[a-z]{2,})\Z/i

  def self.paged(page_number)
    order(admin: :desc, username: :asc).page page_number
  end

  def self.search_and_order(search, page_number)
    if search
      where("username LIKE ?", "%#{search.downcase}%").order(
      admin: :desc, username: :asc
      ).page page_number
    else
      order(admin: :desc, username: :asc).page page_number
    end
  end

  def self.last_signups(count)
    order(created_at: :desc).limit(count).select("id","username","slug","created_at")
  end

  def self.last_signins(count)
    order(last_sign_in_at:
    :desc).limit(count).select("id","username","slug","last_sign_in_at")
  end

  def self.users_count
    where("admin = ? AND locked = ?",false,false).count
  end
end
```

---

**docker-compose.yml**

```
dnsdock:
  image: tonistiigi/dnsdock
  volumes:
    - /var/run/docker.sock:/run/docker.sock
  ports:
    - 172.17.0.1:53:53/udp

db:
  image: postgres
  dns: ["172.17.0.1"]
  environment:
    - DNSDOCK_NAME=db
    - DNSDOCK_IMAGE=awe
  ports:
    - "5432:5432"

mongodb:
  image: mongo
  dns: ["172.17.0.1"]
  environment:
    - DNSDOCK_NAME=mongodb
    - DNSDOCK_IMAGE=awe
rabbitmq:
  image: rabbitmq
  dns: ["172.17.0.1"]
  environment:
    - DNSDOCK_NAME=rabbitmq
    - DNSDOCK_IMAGE=awe
#gemstore:
#  image: busybox
#  volumes:
#    - /gemstore

mainview_m:
  build: mainview_m
  command: bash -c "rm /app/tmp/pids/server.pid ; bundle exec rails s -p 3030 -b '0.0.0.0'"
  dns: ["172.17.0.1"]
  environment:
    - DNSDOCK_NAME=mainview_m
    - DNSDOCK_IMAGE=awe
  volumes:
    - ./mainview_m:/app
  ports:
    - "3030:3030"
  links:
    - db
    - rabbitmq
    - mongodb
    - authentication_m

authentication_m:
  build: authentication_m
  command: bash -c "rm /app/tmp/pids/server.pid ; bundle exec rails s -p 3000 -b '0.0.0.0'"
  dns: ["172.17.0.1"]
  environment:
    - DNSDOCK_NAME=authentication_m
    - DNSDOCK_IMAGE=awe
  volumes:
    - ./authentication_m:/app
  ports:
    - "3000:3000"
  links:
    - db
    - rabbitmq
    - mongodb
```

---

```
session_store.rb
Rails.application.config.session_store :cookie_store, key: '_authentication_m_session'
```

---

Answer (score 0):

ok, after another 10 days we got it. Hope it helps others: There are many traps and we got in the end in more and more because we didn't handle gem versioning well. (Docker bundles everything in the container from the scratch... therefore, we came into the omniauth-oauth2 3.1 issue of defining the callback_url within the oauth strategy.

here is how it works in the most simple way:

provider_doorkeeper:

```
Doorkeeper.configure do
  orm :active_record

  resource_owner_authenticator do
    current_user || begin
      session[:user_return_to] = request.fullpath
      redirect_to new_user_session_url
      end
  end

  admin_authenticator do
    current_user || redirect_to(new_user_session_url)
  end
  default_scopes  :public
end
```

client_strategy_doorkeeper:

```
require 'omniauth-oauth2'

module OmniAuth
  module Strategies
    class Doorkeeper < OmniAuth::Strategies::OAuth2
      option :name, 'doorkeeper'
      option :client_options, {
        site:          ENV['DOORKEEPER_APP_URL'],
        authorize_url: ENV['DOORKEEPER_APP_URL'] + '/oauth/authorize'
      }

      uid {
        raw_info['id']
      }

      info do
        {
          email: raw_info['email'],
        }
      end

      extra do
        { raw_info: raw_info }
      end

      ***def callback_url
        full_host + script_name + callback_path
      end***

      def raw_info
        auth = "Bearer " + access_token.token
        @raw_info = HTTParty.get(ENV['DOORKEEPER_APP_URL'] + "/api/v1/user/current_user", :headers => { "Authorization" => auth})
      end
    end
  end
end
```

client_omniauth_callbacks_controller

```
class Users::OmniauthCallbacksController < Devise::OmniauthCallbacksController
  def self.provides_callback_for(provider)
    class_eval %Q{
      def #{provider}
        @user = User.find_for_oauth(env["omniauth.auth"], current_user)
        if @user.persisted?
          sign_in_and_redirect @user, event: :authentication
          set_flash_message(:notice, :success, kind: "#{provider}".capitalize) if is_navigational_format?
        else
          session["devise.#{provider}_data"] = env["omniauth.auth"]
          redirect_to new_user_registration_url
        end
      end
    }
  end

  [:doorkeeper].each do |provider|
    provides_callback_for provider
  end

end
```